# In bloggers getting error for cookies, how to resolve it?

Tags: blogger

[image]

I am getting this error all of my blogger's blog.
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error. It's a notice to inform you that Blogger will display notification about cookies usage to your blog visitors that live in certain country. There's no need to do anything unless you're using custom template that cause the notification not appearing.

According to Google Blog help forum :

> You can count on the fact that Google is committed to GDPR compliance
>   across products, including Blogger. We are always working to stay
>   compliant, which helps make compliance easier for your blog. We are
>   also committed to providing robust privacy and security protections
>   built into our services. We know security and privacy are important to
>   you, and they are important to us, too. For Google, it’s a priority
>   that your private information is safe.

Blogger forum : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/hReLm9qQwwA;context-place=topicsearchin/blogger/EU